# Stop ReSharper from putting JavaScript function parameter onto new line

Tags: javascript, formatting, resharper, resharper-9.0

How can I stop ReSharper formatting from turning this:

```
define(['Spec'], function (Spec) {

});
```

into this:

```
define(['Spec'],
    function(Spec) {

    });
```

I've tried various combinations of settings but have not hit upon the right one yet.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try changing the following setting to "Simple wrap": `ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | JavaScript | Formatting Style | Line Breaks | Wrapping and chopping | Wrap invocation arguments`